# How to generate jpg thumbnails and browsable html pages from command line?

Tags: graphics, html, jpeg

I am searching for a simple command line tool that takes a bunch of jpg files as input, copies them to some destination and generates some browsable html for it (including index page, preview thumbnails etc.), such that I can upload the results to some static webserver and people can conveniently browse them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

andcoz's answer provided me with a good search term, i.e. just using

```
$ apt-cache search gallery
```

results in some packages matching the above criteria, e.g.

- bins
- [igal2](http://igal.trexler.at/) - Nice looking film reel effect in gallery by default, scaling of original images is not the default (see `--bigy`), homepage and man page are missing some usage examples
- jigl
- [lazygal](http://sousmonlit.dyndns.org/~niol/playa/oss/projects/lazygal/) - Themes are easy to change/adjust, instead of next/previous links small thumbnails (at the left/right), small/medium scaled views by default, `--original` creates links to the original files
- llgal
- [photon](http://www.saillard.org/programs_and_patches/photon/) - Optional slideshow feature via javascript, some scaling and link to original image available
- webmagick

(Under Ubuntu 10.04)

Answer (score 1):

You can hack a solution together with [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/).

Install [Dropbox CLI](http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/DropboxLinuxCLI).

Then copy files to [a public gallery](https://www.dropbox.com/help/18) which presents the images in a [minimally styled format](http://www.dropbox.com/gallery/261312/1/Top10Albums?h=9bd9f4).

Optionally, you could use this [bash upload script](http://www.andreafabrizi.it/?dropbox_uploader).

DropboxCLI has an option to copy the gallery URL

> copygallery - Copies the gallery url to the clipboard

so that you can then share that link...

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, I used [BB Gallery](http://bbgallery.sourceforge.net/). It is very simple and easy to customize (if you know a little of perl).

Answer (score 0):

For creating thumbnails from a bunch of JPGs, my first thought is to use [Netpbm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/). Netpbm is a toolkit for converting images from one format to the other. Once you've banged together a script using Netpbm, you'd have to pull in some other scripting for the creation of the HTML gallery, and the copying and uploading process. Good luck!